# gdk_seat_get_keyboard: assertion 'GDK_IS_SEAT (seat)' failed

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

In

```
WSL version: 0.68.2.0
Kernel version: 5.15.62.1
WSLg version: 1.0.44
MSRDC version: 1.2.3401
Direct3D version: 1.606.4
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22621.608
```

Ubuntu version:
22.04 and 22.10

When I enable **systemd**

(In /etc/wsl.conf:

```
[boot]
systemd=true
```

)

I get this error

> gdk_seat_get_keyboard: assertion 'GDK_IS_SEAT (seat)' failed

when I try to start **gnome-terminal**

What can I do to solve that problem ?

Comment: Please add the version of Ubuntu to your question with EDIT. It may matter.